# threads and LWP in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, lightweight-processes

Is this sentence correct: "All threads in Linux are LWP but not all LWP are threads". Actually, I try to understand thread realisation in **Linux**. pthread_create call clone syscall, but in man clone, I didn't find any reference to LWP.

So, does Linux have LWP at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are user-level threads scheduled/created, and how are kernel level threads created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185134/how-are-user-level-threads-scheduled-created-and-how-are-kernel-level-threads-c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From this blog you can find your answer http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/linux-process-and-threads/

> Threads in Linux are nothing but a flow of execution of the process. A
>   process containing multiple execution flows is known as multi-threaded
>   process.
>
> For a non multi-threaded process there is only execution flow that is
>   the main execution flow and hence it is also known as single threaded
>   process. For Linux kernel , there is no concept of thread. Each thread
>   is viewed by kernel as a separate process but these processes are
>   somewhat different from other normal processes. I will explain the
>   difference in following paragraphs.
>
> Threads are often mixed with the term Light Weight Processes or LWPs.
>   The reason dates back to those times when Linux supported threads at
>   user level only. This means that even a multi-threaded application was
>   viewed by kernel as a single process only. This posed big challenges
>   for the library that managed these user level threads because it had
>   to take care of cases that a thread execution did not hinder if any
>   other thread issued a blocking call.
>
> Later on the implementation changed and processes were attached to
>   each thread so that kernel can take care of them. But, as discussed
>   earlier, Linux kernel does not see them as threads, each thread is
>   viewed as a process inside kernel. These processes are known as light
>   weight processes.
>
> The main difference between a light weight process (LWP) and a normal
>   process is that LWPs share the same address space and other resources like
>   open files etc. As some resources are shared so these processes are
>   considered to be light weight as compared to other normal processes
>   and hence the name light weight processes.
>
> So, effectively we can say that threads and light weight processes are
>   the same. It’s just that thread is a term that is used at user level while
>   light weight process is a term used at kernel level.
>
> From implementation point of view, threads are created using functions
>   exposed by POSIX compliant pthread library in Linux. Internally, the
>   clone() function is used to create a normal as well as a light weight
>   process. This means that to create a normal process fork() is used
>   that further calls clone() with appropriate arguments while to create
>   a thread or LWP, a function from pthread library calls clone() with
>   relevant flags. So, the main difference is generated by using
>   different flags that can be passed to clone() function.
>
> Read more about fork() and clone() on their respective man pages.

Comment: but if "threads and light weight processes are same" why two terms are exist?

Comment: It’s just that thread is a term that is used at user level while light weight process is a term used at kernel level.