# What is the difference between user defined stack and built in stack in use of memory?

Tags: c++, c

I want to use user defined stack for my program which has a large number of recursive calls ? Will it be useful to define user defined stack?

Comment: Depends on the user defined stack, we need to see it.

Comment: Did you mean heap by built in stack ?

Comment: .. or just create a bigger stack if you're on posix.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this.

Primarily, *two*:

(1) Use the CPU/processor stack. There are some variants, each with its own limitations.

(2) Or, recode your function(s) to use a "stack frame" struct that simulates a "stack". The actual function ceases to be recursive. This can be virtually limitless up to whatever the heap will permit

---

For (1) ...

(A) If your system permits, you can issue a `syscall` to extend the process's stack size. There may be limits on how much you can do this and collisions with shared library addresses.

(B) You can `malloc` a large area. With some [somewhat] intricate inline asm trickery, you can swap this area for the stack [and back again] and call your function with this `malloc` area as the stack. Doable, but not for the faint of heart ...

(C) An easier way is to `malloc` a large area. Pass this area to `pthread_attr_setstack`. Then, run your recursive function as a thread using `pthread_create`. Note, you don't really care about multiple threads, it's just an easy way to avoid the "messy" asm trickery.

With (A), *assuming* the stack extend syscall permits, the limit could be all of available memory permitted for stack [up to some system-wide or RLIMIT_* parameter].

With (B) and (C), you have to "guess" and make the `malloc` large enough before you start. After it has been done, the size is fixed and can *not* be extended further.

Actually, that's not quite true. Using the asm trickery repeatedly [when needed], you could simulate a near infinite stack. But, IMO, the overhead of keeping track of these large malloc areas is high enough that I'd opt for (2) below.

---

For (2) ...

This can literally expand/contract as needed. One of the advantages is that you don't need to guess beforehand at how much memory you'll need. The [pseudo] stack can just keep growing as needed [until `malloc` returns `NULL` :-)].

Here is a sample recursive function [treat loosely as pseudo code]:

```
int
myfunc(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    int ret;

    // do some stuff ...

    if (must_recurse)
        ret = myfunc(a + 5,b + 7,c - 6,d + 8);
    else
        ret = 0;

    return ret;
}
```

Here is that function changed to use a `struct` as a stack frame [again, loose pseudo code]:

```
typedef struct stack_frame frame_t;
struct stack_frame {
    frame_t *prev;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

stack_t *free_pool;
#define GROWCOUNT   1000

frame_t *
frame_push(frame_t *prev)
{
    frame_t *cur;

    // NOTE: we can maintain a free pool ...
    while (1) {
        cur = free_pool;

        if (cur != NULL) {
            free_pool = cur->prev;
            break;
        }

        // refill free pool from heap ...
        free_pool = calloc(GROWCOUNT,sizeof(stack_t));
        if (free_pool == NULL) {
            printf("frame_push: no memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        cur = free_pool;
        for (int count = GROWCOUNT;  count > 0;  --count, ++cur)
            cur->prev = cur + 1;
        cur->prev = NULL;
    }

    if (prev != NULL) {
        *cur = *prev;
        cur->prev = prev;

        cur->a += 5;
        cur->b += 7;
        cur->c += 6;
        cur->d += 8;
    }
    else
        memset(cur,0,sizeof(frame_t));

    return cur;
}

frame_t *
frame_pop(frame_t *cur)
{
    frame_t *prev;

    prev = cur->prev;

    cur->prev = free_pool;
    free_pool = cur;

    return prev;
}

int
myfunc(void)
{
    int ret;
    stack_t *cur;

    cur = frame_push(NULL);

    // set initial conditions in cur...

    while (1) {
        // do stuff ...

        if (must_recurse) {
            cur = frame_push(cur);
            must_recurse = 0;
            continue;
        }

        // pop stack
        cur = frame_pop(cur);
        if (cur == NULL)
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of functions, objects, variable and user defined structures use memory spaces which is control by OS and compiler. So, it means your defined stack works under a general memory space which is specified for the stack of your process in OS. As a result, it does not have a big difference, but you can define an optimized structure with high efficiency to use this general stack much more better.