# User-level Thread Mapping in "Linux"

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

According to the [video](https://youtu.be/x0BYhaEEXcE), which is from the Introductory Operating Systems course in Udacity:

> *For a user-level thread to actually execute first, it must be associated with a kernel-level thread. And then, the OS level scheduler must schedule that kernel-level thread onto a CPU.*

According to [Remzi H. Arpaci-Dusseau's book (Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces) in chapter 6](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf):

> *We have described some key low-level mechanisms to implement CPU
>   virtualization, a set of techniques which we collectively refer to as limited
>   direct execution. The basic idea is straightforward: just run the program
>   you want to run on the CPU, but first make sure to set up the hardware
>   so as to limit what the process can do without OS assistance.*
>
> *This general approach is taken in real life as well. For example, those
>   of you who have children, or, at least, have heard of children, may be
>   familiar with the concept of baby proofing a room: locking cabinets containing
>   dangerous stuff and covering electrical sockets. When the room is
>   thus readied, you can let your baby roam freely, secure in the knowledge
>   that the most dangerous aspects of the room have been restricted.*
>
> *In an analogous manner, the OS “baby proofs” the CPU, by first (during
>   boot time) setting up the trap handlers and starting an interrupt timer,
>   and then by only running processes in a restricted mode. By doing so, the
>   OS can feel quite assured that processes can run efficiently, only requiring
>   OS intervention to perform privileged operations or when they have
>   monopolized the CPU for too long and thus need to be switched out.*

First quote states a kernel-level thread has to associated with a user-level thread to run, but according to the second quote, OS directly executes the user-level thread but under strict control, without any associations.

**Questions:**

**1)** I'm a newbie Linux user. Which of the above approach is more correct for Linux operating system?

**2)** Yes there are quite many posts and links about Multithreading models in the internet. But can't find a single example code. Can you give a simple example C code on One-to-One and Many-to-One for Linux?

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185134/how-are-user-level-threads-scheduled-created-and-how-are-kernel-level-threads-c/39185831#39185831

Comment: Great intro article [light-weight-processes-dissecting-linux-threads](http://opensourceforu.com/2011/08/light-weight-processes-dissecting-linux-threads/)