# User thread, Kernel thread, software thread and hardware thread

Tags: multithreading

I'm studying thread and multithreading concepts and I ran into different kinds of thread:

1. User thread: supported above the kernel and are managed without the kernel.
2. Kernel thread: supported and managed directly by the operating system.
3. Software thread: threads of execution managed by the operating system.
4. Hardware thread: a feature of some processors that allow better utilization of the processor under some circumstances.

Can anyone clarify the difference between these types of threads (I'm confused)?

Thanks

Comment: Note: When anybody talks about the design of the Linux kernel, "kernel thread" means something different in that context from the way you're using it here. [Linux kernel threads](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785883057/1/ch01lvl1sec13/kernel-threads) are completely hidden from normal, "user mode" applicaton programs. A Linux developer probably would call your "kernel thread" a _native thread,_ and probably would call your "user thread" a _green thread._

Comment: See my answer: [How are user-level threads scheduled/created, and how are kernel level threads created?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185831/5382650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hardware thread" is a bad name. It was chosen as a term of art by CPU designers, without much regard for what software developers think "thread" means.

When an operating system interrupts a running thread so that some other thread may be allowed to use the CPU, it must save enough of the state of the CPU so that the thread can be resumed again later on. Mostly that saved state consists of the program counter, the stack pointer, and other CPU registers that are part of the [*programmer's model* of the CPU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/365367/69405).

A so-called "[hyperthreaded CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)" has two or more complete sets of those registers. That allows it to execute instructions on behalf of two or more program threads without any need for the operating system to intervene.

Experts in the field like nice, short names for things. Instead of talking about "complete sets of context registers," they just call them "hardware threads."

Comment: Thanks. Now hardware thread is clear for me. Just to be sure, "software thread" is exactly the thread that we can create using ```pthread``` library in C?

Answer (score 5):

Hardware thread is what allows you to actually run things in parallel (which is not the same as concurrently). These corresspond to number of your CPU cores (with nuances like hyperthreading, which can double the number of cores).

On top of that are OS (kernel) threads. Its an abstraction provided by your OS. The OS will map them to hardware threads. It does this via internal scheduler, and we have little to no control over that. Note that in theory there may be arbitrarily many OS threads (if there are not enough cores to handle them they simply wait for CPU), although the price for so called context switch limits it to few thousands, maybe more.

User threads (a.k.a. green threads, coroutines, etc. they have many names) is an abstraction provided by your software (e.g. programming language and its runtime). They run on top of OS threads, and are mapped to them via internal (but in user space) scheduler. They tend to perform better than OS threads (especially with i/o bound tasks) because they have lower context switch overhead, plus they can take advantage of async apis (e.g. nonblocking sockets) without spawning OS threads (which is costly as well). Since they are lightweight, you can spawn lots of them. Some people claim to run millions of such threads at a time. I personally have seen tens of thousands without issues.

I've never seen the term "software thread" though. But depending on context it means either user or kernel thread. Unlikely it means anything else.

Btw no real code can run without some OS support. It can be limited, if for example you don't want things to run in parallel. But as soon as you want true parallelism there is no escape from OS threads. The internal scheduler for user threads have to spawn OS threads and map user threads to them in some way. Although typically it is an invisible implemention detail.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. About the hardware thread, does it a unit in CPU?It's still not clear to me.

Comment: If you buy a CPU with say 8 cores it means it has 8 hardware threads. It means it can run 8 instructions in parallel.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I need to implement a hardware thread in my own CPU simulator so I need to know what is exactly. Is it an execution unit in the CPU?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask whoever gave you that task? I suppose hardware thread and execution unit are closely related terms.